# Aspell installed but not in the list of pyenchant providers

Tags: python, dll, aspell, pyenchant

I'm currently trying to improve the spelling of some textual data, and to do that I'm using pyEnchant 1.6.8 (python3.3, Windows 8). As far as providers go, only Myspell and Ispell are available.

I would like to try to use Aspell, as I've read somewhere it was more efficient when it comes to the store_replacement method. Aspell is installed on the computer I'm using, but does not show in the providers list :

```
b = enchant.Broker()

b.describe()
[<Enchant: Ispell Provider>, <Enchant: Myspell Provider>]
```

Also, I've tried to check what's in the directory where the .dll are ([...]\WINPYTHON.3355\python-3.3.5\Lib\site-packages\enchant\lib\enchant), and there are only *libenchant_ispell.dll* and *libenchant_myspell.dll*, no aspell file there.

As naive as it may be, I've tried to copy an Aspell .dll file there, but it didn't improve anything.

Does anyone have an idea, please?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my Mac:
After installing pyenchant (into a Python 3.6 conda environment) via

```
pip install pyenchant
```

Python says

```
>>> import enchant
>>> b = enchant.Broker()
>>> b.describe()
[<Enchant: Ispell Provider>, <Enchant: Myspell Provider>]
```

I was able to solve the problem (for my purposes) by uninstalling this version of pyenchant with pip, and cloning the git repository at https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant into my home directory. After running

```
pip install ~/pyenchant/
```

to install the local copy of the package, I see that I now have *only* Aspell provider:

```
>>> import enchant
>>> b = enchant.Broker()
>>> b.describe()
[<Enchant: Aspell Provider>]
```